# Android - How to capture volume buttons events when the phone is in stand by

Tags: android, events, mobile, button

I need your help. I want to implement the volume buttons.

I want to know how can I capture volume button events when the phone is in stand-by?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a broadcast receiver for receiving your button events like this,

```
public class YourBoardcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        /* handle media button intent here by reading contents */
        /* of EXTRA_KEY_EVENT to know which key was pressed    */
    }
}
```

}

and in manifest,

```
<receiver android:name="YourBoardcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            </intent-filter>
```